# Flutter IOS - Keep all targets' versions and build numbers up-to-date

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

By default, only the Runner target's version and build number stay up-to-date.

I've had to add another target for a plugin I'm using, and at the moment I have to manually keep its version and build number up-to-date.

The reason I care about it is because App Store keeps warning me everytime I upload a build where the targets' versions and build numbers are not in sync.

**How can I keep the second target's version and build number up-to-date automatically as well? I suppose it should somehow be done in the Podfile?**

Answer (score 3):

I, too, was facing the same problem and used to manually change the version every-time before archiving.

If you are still facing this issue, I have got a work around for this. You can try adding the below code into build phase of the main Target.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    buildNumber=$(cut -d'=' -f2 <<< $(cat Flutter/Generated.xcconfig | grep FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER))
    buildName=$(cut -d'=' -f2 <<< $(cat Flutter/Generated.xcconfig | grep FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME))
    target1="firstTargetName"
    target2="secondTargetName"
    
    echo "kushal___ $buildNumber"
    echo "kushal___ $buildName"
    
    #/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
    #/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $buildName" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
    
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$SRCROOT/$target1/Info.plist"
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $buildName" "$SRCROOT/$target1/Info.plist"
    
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$SRCROOT/$target2/Info.plist"
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $buildName" "$SRCROOT/$target2/Info.plist"
```

[image]

Comment: i suppose values like "stylinotificationservice" or "styliNotificationContent" need to be adjusted to our own target names ;) ?

Comment: @ChristianX,
Thanks for identifying this, i forgot to mention that. Yes here stylinotificationservice and styliNotificationContent are 2 targets, which have to be replaced with the targets names as per the project :) .

Comment: @ChristianX, have edited the code with target1 and target2, so that it would make more sense and easier to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

First you should add a new xcconfig file to  you project(Version.xcconfig).
The xcconfig file should look like this(must override the OTHER_LDFLAGS variable ):

```
#include "Flutter/Generated.xcconfig"
OTHER_LDFLAGS=
```

Then set you new targets to use the configuration.
[image]

Last just set your target info.plist's version and build number to Flutter build name and number.
[image]

Build your project in flutter, then all the target's version will be just the same as you set in you pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'permission_handler' from project 'Pods')
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in parallel

Comment: i have the above error following your solution during 'flutter build ipa' that i haven't without versionconfig.xcconfig